# Add text to all first menu option

Tags: jquery, html, select, input

In my HTML I have:

```
<select>
    <option value></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    ...
</select>
<select>
    <option value></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    ...
</select>
<select>
    <option value></option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    ...
</select>
...
```

All select tags are without id or class.
I want to set the text of the first options

Ex:

```
<select>
    <option value>My Text</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value>My Text</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
...
```

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: why you dont want id or class for select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get first option using **[`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)** pseudo-class selector and update text content using **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** method.

```
$('select option:first-child').text('My text')
```

```js
$('select option:first-child').text('My text')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select option:nth-child(1)').text('My Text')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

<select>
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

<select>
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

...
```

1. Use `:nth-child(1)` to get the first option
2. Use `.text()` to set the text

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a common function in which we have to pass id of the dropdown and text which we want to add for first option of the dropdown. Please look in to below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first">
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

<select  id="third">
<option value></option>
<option value="1">One</option>
...
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function firstValueSelect(id,value){
        $('#'+id+' option:first-child').text(value);
    }
    firstValueSelect("first","test first");
    firstValueSelect("second","test second");
</script>
```